# How to center Column widget horizontally in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I was learning Flutter and wanted to learn to how structure layout. Thus, I decided to use column widget and wanted to ask how to center horizontally column widget having this code: import

```
'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
            body: SafeArea(
                child: Column(

              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/avatar.jpeg'),
                ),
                Text('SAM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                        fontSize: 50.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text('Flutter developer',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        // fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              ],
            ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try this  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya, already tried but not working since the width is narrow by default and I think your advice will work if the width will be 100% of the width of screen. I do not know how to increase width

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the `Column` `crossAxisAlignment` property to `CrossAxisAlignment.center`

Try wrapping your `Column` in a `Container` widget and give it a width property.

Check the code below:
It works perfectly:

```
'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
            body: SafeArea(
                Container(
                // set the height property to take the screen width
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(
              // set the crossAxisAlignment property to center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/avatar.jpeg'),
                ),
                Text('SAM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                        fontSize: 50.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text('Flutter developer',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        // fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              ],
            ))),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: already tried to add crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center BUT not working((

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your screen is not tacking whole width, so it is centre widget, whatever sized is used.

To used whole width you can provide container size to max size, which will force widget to use full width and it will centre widget.

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // added
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/crown 1.png'),
                ),
                Text('SAM',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                        fontSize: 50.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text('Flutter developer',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        // fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              ],
            ),
          ))),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: If you want Column to be center aligned:

```
//First Way: Use Column Widget inside Center Widget

    Center(
     child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[]
     )

//Second Way: Use Container Widget and set alignment to center

 Container(
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[]
                )
          )
```

Case 2: If you want Column children to be center aligned

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to align widgets in center (vertically and horizontally), you can use

```
Center(
 child: Column(
 children: <Widget>[]
 )
```

if you want to align horizontally but at the top of the screen then

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // to cover all the area

    children: [
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [Text("test data")],
      )
    ],
  )
```

worked for me.

And if you want to center vertically and at the beginning of the screen then

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // to cover all the area
    children: [
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [Text("test data")],
      )
    ],
```

works as well.